# How to make T extends two types?

Tags: dart

```dart
void foo<T extends num, String> (T t) {
  if (t is String) {
    String s = t; // Error
  }
}
```

> A value of type 'T' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.

Comment: T can't do that.

Comment: There is no point in having a generic T when you work around it with `if`-`is` anyway. Just use `dynamic`, or provide a method with two optional parameters, one of each type.

Comment: @nvoigt `dynamic` means I can provide anything (which I don't want) and creating an optional parameter would require to me work with assert because I don't want to provide both `num` and `String` at the same time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax to specify that a generic type implement multiple interfaces, so there is no way for this to work with compile-time checks.

Furthermore, your particular example can't work because `num` and `String` cannot be extended nor implemented, so it's impossible to have a type that implements both.

If we change your example, which relies on a runtime check, to use two custom types, it still won't work:

```dart
class C1 {}

class C2 {
  void f() => print('C2.f');
}

class C3 implements C1, C2 {
  @override
  void f() => print('C3.f');
}

void foo<T extends C1>(T t) {
  if (t is C2) {
    t.f(); // 'f' isn't defined for the type <unknown>
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2047: `t` isn't related to `C2`, so the `is C2` check unfortunately will not automatically promote it to `C2`.  You instead can use a runtime cast:

```dart
void foo<T extends C1>(T t) {
  if (t is C2) {
    (t as C2).f();
  }
}
```

or upcast to `Object`/`dynamic` first:

```dart
void foo<T extends C1>(T t) {
  Object t0 = t;
  if (t0 is C2) {
    t0.f();
  }
}
```

But really you should just use `T extends C3` if possible.

Comment: I was aware of `as` part (which I think you mentioned in one of my posts before) but this the `Object` workaround is kinda nice.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with base Dart as your generic type `T` can only extends one class.
The only way I would see such a behavior feasible would be by using a 3rd party packages such as [dartz](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz) with its [`Either`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartz/latest/dartz/Either-class.html) type.

### Example

```dart
void foo<T extends num>(Either<T, String> t) {
  final String s;
  if (t.isRight()) {
    s = (t as Right<T, String>).value;
  } else {
    s = (t as Left<T, String>).value.toStringAsFixed(3);
  }
  print(s);
}

foo(Left(1.0)); // prints '1.000'
foo<int>(Right('bar')); // prints 'bar'
```